# DBSCAN cluster with metric='russellrao'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-computing, dbscan

I met a problem when I use sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.
If I use `DBSCAN(metric="russellrao")`, which data format should be?
I try 2 ways and both return `pred = [-1 -1 -1 ..., -1 -1 -1]` . You can see the 2 data format below.

```
npy = df2.values
y_pred = DBSCAN(metric="russellrao").fit_predict(npy)
```

1.
npy = [image]

2.
npy = [image]

print y_pred 
[-1 -1 -1 ..., -1 -1 -1]

so,which format is the right anwser?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please avoid screenshots, use copy-paste and format it accordingly. It is useless to get help, heavier in term of bytes and not handy at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to choose the other DBSCAN parameters appropriately.

IMHO, sklearn should *not* have defaults for them. In particular epsilon depends very much on your data set and metric, so the default will almost always be a bad choice. Instead of providing bad defaults, it should force users to choose the parameters.

Comment: yes,I know,but I just don't sure that metric has the parameter "russellrao".How can I find the all parameters?The document(http://sklearn.lzjqsdd.com/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html#sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN) is too berif.

Comment: If you follow the rabbit into the documentation, you can get a list of efficiently supported metrics. Or you add your own.